# Get the index of an original list after removing entries

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a list:

```
original_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I then have another list with indexes of which indexes I have to remove from the `original_list`:

```
remove_list = [0, 4, 6]
```

I then use Numpy to remove/delete these indexes:

```
final_list = np.delete(original_list, remove_list, axis = 0]
```

All good, let's say I now wish to find the max value of the `final_list` with `np.amax(final_list)`. Is there now any way I can figure out which index this value had in the `original_list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option 1: `np.where`:

```
>>> np.where(original_list == np.amax(final_list))
(array([8]),)
```

## Option 2: `.index()`

```
>>> original_list.index(np.amax(final_list))
8
```

Note: If there are more than one matching indices, this method will only return the first / smallest index. If you want all indices, use `np.where` as above

Comment: Could the downvoter let me know why this doesn't answer the question? Or why they downvoted?

Comment: No reason. I think this is the best way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way you could do this,

```
mask = np.zeros(original_list.shape, dtype=np.bool)
mask[remove_list] = True

np.ma.MaskedArray(original_list, mask=mask).argmax()
```